# Lost access to Jenkins without logs

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed in my ubuntu machine and it was working fine but suddently stopped being accessible through the browser.
`sudo systemctl status jenkins` shows that it's active, and logs say that it's fully up and running.

I tried restarting the services but it didn't work.

Jenkins is not listening to port

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the machine couldn't support Jenkins and SonarQube working together so Jenkins just failed when I installed SonarQube